# How to Open Realm(JavaScript) object asynchronously and use it with services

Tags: javascript, realm

I am using below code in my project to open realm asynchronously and use it with the services.

### RmProfile.js:

```
import Realm from 'realm';
const PrflSchema = {
  name: 'Profile',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  properties: {
    id            : {type: 'int'},
    mob            : {type: 'int'},
    name        : {type: 'string'},
  }
};

let RmPrfl;

Realm.open({
      schema: [PrflSchema],
      schemaVersion: 0
    }).then(realm => {
        RmPrfl = realm;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('Error in Opening PrflSchema');
        console.log(error);
      });

let ProfileServices= {
    getName: function(id) {
        let PrflInfo=RmPrfl.objectForPrimaryKey('Profile', id);
        if(PrflInfo){
            return PrflInfo.name;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
module.exports = ProfileServices;
```

Now to use the realm services in other files i am simply trying to export

### Profile.js:

```
import PrflSrvcs from './ProfileServices'
console.log(PrflSrvcs.getName('1253'));
```

here the services getting exported but the error is coming like RmPrfl is undefined. This happens as the Realm.Open() is asynchronously executed and before its execution ends, the ProfileServices is executed.

So as I am new to Realm, can anyone guide me, How to asynchronous transactions using Realm JavaScript.

Any example will be good to understand.

Thank you..

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just wrap it all in a promise e.g.

```
let ProfileServices = () => {
    getName: function(id) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Realm.open({
              schema: [PrflSchema],
              schemaVersion: 0
          })
          .then(realm => {
              let PrflInfo = realm.objectForPrimaryKey('Profile', id);
              resolve(PrflInfo || false)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log('Error in Opening PrflSchema');
              console.log(error);
              reject(error)
          });
      })
    }
}

module.exports = ProfileServices

import PrflSrvcs from './ProfileServices'
PrflSrvcs.getName('1253')
  .then(name => { console.log(name) });
```

You probably don't want to be opening the realm for every query though, you can cache it and check for the existence before running the open.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have figured it out from other sources long back, so my implementation more like your answer...

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear in the documentation, but it seems Realm.open(config) caches the promised realm itself, so you can actually just use that API for every query.

```
# Initial Ream.open():  took 176.50000000139698 milliseconds.
# Manually Cached:      took 0.5999999993946403 milliseconds.
# Second Realm.open():  took 0.19999999494757503 milliseconds.
```

So manually caching just creates a little extra overhead without simplifying the API for accessing the realm.

Here's the caching function I used:

```js
    private realm(): Promise<Realm> {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.cachedRealm) {
          resolve(this.cachedRealm)
        } else {
          Realm.open(this.config)
            .then(realm => {
              this.cachedRealm = realm
              resolve(realm)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
                reject(error)
            });
        }
      })
    }
```